# Can't get setenv to work in .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

SetEnv doesn't seem to work for me. I tried this in my .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^192\.168\.0$ ip_ok
<IfDefine !ip_ok>
  AuthName "Guest Login"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/lib/ok_users/guests.users
  require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

and I had to provide username/password credentials even though my ip is 192.168.0.10 and the server (centos5 / xampp for linux 1.6.8a) is 192.168.0.1

So I tried this:

```
SetEnv ip_ok
<IfDefine !ip_ok>
  AuthName "Guest Login"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/lib/ok_users/guests.users
  require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

but setenv does not set ip_ok, and I still get challenged.

Then I tried this:

```
SetEnv ip_ok
<IfDefine ip_ok>
  AuthName "Guest Login"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/lib/ok_users/guests.users
  require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

and I don't get challenged. Therefore IfDefine is working.

Any ideas why I can't get SetEnv and SetEnvIf to work?? I've googled and read but can't crack it.

Comment: For future reference, this looks like more of a [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) question too.

Comment: Also, I'd sugget using Digest authentication instead of Basic

Answer (score 1):

`<IfDefine>` doesn't work like you're thinking. It examines parameters passed to [`httpd` at startup](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ifdefine) via `-Dparameter` (or [`Define`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#define) in Apache 2.3), not the environment variables.

That's OK though, you should be able to do what you want like this instead:

```
Order allow,deny
AuthName "Guest Login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/lib/ok_users/guests.users
Require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.0
Satisfy Any
```

The[`Satisfy` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#satisfy), when set to `Any`, allows you to be granted access if you pass the host verification, *or* if you've supplied the password.